# need to categorize wordpress posts into subfolders without individually installing wordpress in subfolders

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, subdirectory

i am currently working on a wordpress site related to sports. all my posts are at the same place categorized into football, tennis, etc. i want to change the structure of my blog, such as for football, it should be `domain.com/football` and for tennis, it should be `domain.com/tennis` and so on. one way is to install wordpress in all the subfolders and import the categorized posts, but that would result in maintaining multiple wordpress websites. is there any way or any wordpress plugin by which i can do the same, but using just one wordpress site? thanks. i use cpanel.

P.S. well, its not really necessary to be any subfolder, but all i need is the address bar showing `domain.com/*sports_name*` in it. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You would go to `Settings -> Permalinks` and set a custom permalink structure of `/%category%/%postname%/`

Then you create categories such as 'tennis' and 'football' and add posts to the relevant categories.

The Codex entry on permalinks is here - https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/

In times gone by that permalink structure wasn't recommended for really big blogs due to performance reasons but my understanding (bracing for downvotes!) is that that is no longer the case.

Comment: I think your Answer lacks the removal of `category` in `http://example.com/category/cat-name/`. SEO by Yoast has an option to remove the category base, so the OP ends up with the desired result.

Comment: @brasofilo - thanks for the tip on the category base, should depend on his category structure, no? Hopefully that will help the OP.